# Possible for an app to start an VPN session?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is it possible on iOS4 to start the built-in VPN service? If it is configured and all.
To start it and get a message when it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible using the public API.

Comment: could you point that out where in the documentation that it is not allowed, or is it just not mentioned at all?

Comment: It's just not mentioned at all.